# How can I use CreateTimerQueueTimer to create a high resolution timer in C#?

Tags: c#, timer

I've used a Windows multimedia dll to created a high resolution timer with

**[timSetEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713423(VS.85).aspx)**

But the `timeSetEvent()` page recommends the use of:

**[CreateTimerQueueTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485(VS.85).aspx)**

How can I use CreateTimerQueueTimer() to execute a method every 10 milliseconds in C#?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a link to a C# wrapper for `CreateTimerQueueTimer`:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/csharpgeneral/thread/822aed2d-dca0-4a8e-8130-20fab69557d2

(scroll down to the last post by `Hobz` for the sample class)

I just tried this out myself and it works fine.  One thing you'll need to add, though, is a call to `timeBeginPeriod(1)` before starting the timer in order to set your system to high-resolution.  `timeSetEvent` calls `timeBeginPeriod` internally, which is why some people mistakenly assume that it creates a higher-resolution timer.

Comment: @MusiGenesis- I tried to use this code, but I am getting a stackoverlow exception.  and what do you mean by 'a call to timeBeginPeriod(1)'? I could not find such a function

Answer (score 3):

The callback passed to CreateTimerQueueTimer is expected to be an *unmanaged* function which will exist for the lifetime of the callbacks. The managed delegate can move about in memory but [the underlying stub created by the marshalling will not do this so there is no need to pin the delegate](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/05/06/51385.aspx). There is however a need to keep the delegate from being garbage collected since the pointer from unmanaged code is not sufficient to keep it alive. You must therefore ensure that either the delegate is kept alive by some managed reference being maintained (Perhaps through the use of [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx)

The PVOID Parameter which is passed to the callback function must be fixed in memory since again, the unmanaged function expects it not to move about after the function returns. In .Net this pinning happens (efficiently) automatically but only for the life of the called function. Thus if you are using a reference to some managed object (say by getting an IntPtr to it) the underlying object must be pinned (again the GCHandle can be used for that in a subtly different way). To see if this is the problem try using IntPtr.Zero as the parameter to test if it works.

If this solves things you will need to either allocate your parameter as raw bytes in the unmanaged heap (and marshal accordingly), use some blittable type that is safe to put into something of size PVOID (like an Int32) or use the GCHandle technique above to maintain a stable pointer to a managed instance, this will have significant performance implications if done wrongly.

Comment: You generally don't have to pin delegates passed to API functions, as the InteropServices handle that stuff. You *do* have to make sure that your app maintains a reference to the delegate so that it isn't garbage-collected. Pinning is normally only necessary when passing chunks of memory from the managed world into the unmanaged world (which expects things to stay where they are).

Comment: @MusiGenesis, this is what I was referring to by "In .Net this is almost certain to happen to anything you pass in.", I probably should have called that out as being specific to PInvoke. Likewise I saw no reason to mention the need to keep a reference because P/Invoke does that for you if it's required: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23acw07k.aspx

Comment: PInvoke definitely doesn't maintain delegate references for you. The compiler will happily let you call CreateTimerQueueTimer and pass in `new TimerCallback(...)` as a parameter. This will even run successfully for awhile, until the delegate you created with `new` happens to be garbage collected.

Comment: @Musi ah you mean if the delegate is referenced as a callback after the PInvoke function has returned, yes indeed I will make that clear in the answer.

Comment: @Shuggy: I have to reiterate that you don't need to pin the delegate with `GCHandle` in order to use `CreateTimerQueueTimer`. In fact, you *can't* pin a delegate with `GCHandle`.

Comment: @Musi ah yes, the PInvoke deals with it via an unmanaged stub. I wasn't aware of this. I will add links to why.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use timeSetEvent because its results are more consistent. On average modern hardware, for small intervals, the deviations in length of the intervals are about ten times smaller than when using CreateTimerQueueTimer. And that's assuming you didn't forget to increase the timer resolution before calling CreateTimerQueueTimer, otherwise the difference would be even bigger. So use timeSetEvent instead.

Comment: Looks like timeSetEvent  is deprecated.